# NullReferenceException in copy/ paste of image

Tags: c#

I am getting an error by implementing this simple  code. I donot understand where I am doing mistake.

// ERROR

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in ImageCSharp.exe
>   Additional information: Der Objektverweis wurde nicht auf eine Objektinstanz festgelegt.

I can get clipboard text but why i can't get /set image.

//CODE

```
    public void copy()
    {
        // Determine the active child form.
        fImage activeChild = this.ActiveMdiChild as fImage;
        if (activeChild != null)
        {
            PictureBox mypicbox = activeChild.picbox;
            string win_name = activeChild.Tag.ToString();
            Clipboard.SetImage(mypicbox.Image);
            Clipboard.SetText(win_name);

        }
    }

    private void paste()
    {

       Image im=  Clipboard.GetImage();
       this.pictureBox1.Image = im;
       MessageBox.Show(im.Size.ToString());

    }
```

regards,

Comment: Which line is throwing the exception?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  Clipboard.SetText(win_name);
```

That dumps the image off the clipboard, it can only hold one item.  Delete the line to solve your problem.  And code defensively:

```
    private void paste() {
        if (Clipboard.ContainsImage()) {
            Image im = Clipboard.GetImage();
            if (this.pictureBox1.Image != null) this.pictureBox1.Dispose();
            this.pictureBox1.Image = im;
        }
    }
```

To get both pieces of info on the clipboard, first declare a little helper class to store this info.  For example:

```
    [Serializable]
    private class Clipdata {
        public Image Image { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }

    private void CopyButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        var data = new Clipdata { Image = pictureBox1.Image, Name = textBox1.Text };
        Clipboard.SetDataObject(data);
    }
    private void PasteButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        string fmt = typeof(Clipdata).FullName;
        if (Clipboard.ContainsData(fmt)) {
            var data = (Clipdata)Clipboard.GetDataObject().GetData(fmt);
            if (pictureBox1.Image != null) pictureBox1.Image.Dispose();
            pictureBox1.Image = data.Image;
            textBox1.Text = data.Name;
        }
    }
```

Comment: thanx.you are right. But This is exactly where I got problem. I need image as well as win_name. How can I have that??? (PLease answer it thanx)

Comment: @sayyad - post updated.  Beware that you lose the ability to paste into other apps.

Answer (score 1):

Not an answer to your question, but following won't set the image as well as text to the clipboard. i.e. your code will set the text to the clipboard

```
Clipboard.SetImage(mypicbox.Image);
Clipboard.SetText(win_name);
```

The above code is trying to set the image to the clipboard, followed by text.
i.e. clipboard will contain one item, which is text as per your code.

And I assume because of that the code inside `paste` which expects an image to be in clipboard, is throwing exception on `MessageBox.Show(img.Size.ToString());`.

Comment: first of all thanx. you and Hans are right. But This is exactly where I got problem. I need image as well as win_name. How can I have that??? (PLease answer it thanx)