# Copying text along with its formatting from a RichTextBox

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms, richtextbox, clipboard

How to copy the text in a RichTextBox along with its formatting to a wordpad or webbrowser?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Just like with copying plain text, you would use the [`Clipboard.SetText` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6eahsf3w.aspx). This clears the current contents of the Windows clipboard and adds the specified text to it.

To copy formatted text, you need to use the [overload of that method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tbfb3z56.aspx) that accepts a [`TextDataFormat`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.textdataformat.aspx) parameter. That allows you to specify the format of the text that you wish to copy to the clipboard. In this case, you would specify `TextDataFormat.Rtf`, or text consisting of rich text format data.

Of course, for this to work, you will also have to use the [`Rtf` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.richtextbox.rtf.aspx) of the `RichTextBox` control to extract its text with RTF formatting. You cannot use the regular [`Text` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.richtextbox.text.aspx) because it does not include the RTF formatting information. As the documentation warns:

> The `Text` property does not return any information about the formatting applied to the contents of the `RichTextBox`. To get the rich text formatting (RTF) codes, use the `Rtf` property.

Sample code:

```
' Get the text from your rich text box
Dim textContents As String = myRichTextBox.Rtf

' Copy the text to the clipboard
Clipboard.SetText(textContents, TextDataFormat.Rtf)
```

And once the text is on the clipboard, you (or the user of your application) can paste it wherever you like. To paste the text programmatically, you will use the [`Clipboard.GetText` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/944ft9kf.aspx) that also accepts a `TextDataFormat` parameter. For example:

```
' Verify that the clipboard contains text
If (Clipboard.ContainsText(TextDataFormat.Rtf)) Then
    ' Paste the text contained on the clipboard into a DIFFERENT RichTextBox
    myOtherRichTextBox.Rtf = Clipboard.GetText(TextDataFormat.Rtf)
End If
```

Comment: Will it also copy the images in the RichTextBox and how do I convert it to html ?

Comment: @abcd: I don't know if it will copy the images or not. I suspect that it won't, but you'll have to try it and see. You're set up with an environment much more conducive to testing this at the moment than I am. If you want to use HTML format, change `TextDataFormat.Rtf` to `TextDataFormat.Html`.

Comment: @cody Thanks I will try that and report back

Comment: @cody it didnt work,when i convert to rtf it looks gibberish anyway so that when it is exported to html its gibberish image goes back to normal image ?

Comment: @abcd: RTF format doesn't copy images, you mean? I'm not surprised. Did you also try HTML format? You may find that applications like Microsoft Word that support copying images and text implement this in a binary format, rather than one of the standard formats. That's going to be a real pain to get right, particularly because there's no guarantee that other applications will accept your input.

Comment: @cody `Clipboard.GetText(TextDataFormat.html)`  how do I hold this in a variable , it says String Datat type cannot be used.

Comment: @abcd: Not sure why it says that. I've never actually used it myself, but the example on MSDN uses a string variable. It's possible you've run into a bug in WinForms. This [blog article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jmstall/archive/2007/01/21/html-clipboard.aspx) looks promising. The [sample code is here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jmstall/archive/2007/01/21/sample-code-html-clipboard.aspx), which appears to provide a complete implementation of a class that allows you to copy and paste HTML fragments to the clipboard.

Comment: @abcd: You're in luck there, too. The same guy has an [RTF to HTML converter posted](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jmstall/archive/2006/10/20/rtf_5f00_html.aspx) as well. It may not be entirely complete, but it might give you a head start on implementing this yourself. There's no easy, built-in way of converting RTF to HTML. They're not the same format. Like I mentioned before, if you need an image *and* text on the clipboard at the same time, you might be better off with a binary format. Check Hans's answer to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4634476/).

Comment: @cody Is there any free vb.net component for converting rtf to html ?

Comment: @abcd: Oh, you mean because the sample on that blog is in C#? Yeah, you caught me. I think of the languages as identical because I can convert between them in my head. You should be able to translate that one using a service like [this one](http://www.developerfusion.com/tools/convert/csharp-to-vb/). Aside from the syntax, they're pretty much equivalent.

Comment: @Cody I was going to do the same , just wanted to make sure if there existed a free component or not

Comment: @abcd: I just don't think it's a common use case. RTF and HTML are sufficiently different formats that there isn't a lot of conversion going on. I'm still not clear on what you're ultimately trying to accomplish. Maybe there's a better way.

Comment: @cody I converted and pasted the codes in a vb window form and executed it ... Then copied my rtf code to so that it goes to the clipboard , after this I should get a out.html file ... where is that file ? , I cant find that in the current directory !

Comment: @abcd: Copying it to the clipboard doesn't produce a file on disk. It's the same clipboard you use when you use "Copy" and "Paste" from an application's "Edit" menu. You have to *paste* it somewhere first.

Comment: @abcd: Uh, and just for completeness, if you are just trying to save the contents of a `RichTextBox` to a *file*, you can bypass the clipboard altogether. Much simpler to use the [`SaveFile` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.richtextbox.savefile.aspx) of the `RichTextBox` to do that. You can choose between different formats. You'll find a [complete sample here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ch779a3b.aspx). That's what I meant about wondering what you're ultimately trying to accomplish, because there may be a better way.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar situation where I was copying from my VB .net application and had tried \r\n, \r, \n, vbCrLf, Chr(13), Chr(10), Chr(13) & Chr(10), etc. The new lines would appear if I pasted into Word or Wordpad, but not into Notepad. Finally I used ControlChars.NewLine where I had been using vbCrLf, and it worked. So, to summarize:
Clipboard.SetText("This is one line" & ControlChars.Newline & "and this bad boy is the second.")
And that works correctly. Hope it works for you!

Answer (score 1):

I used this simple event handlers (which use the built-in copy/paste methods of the richtextbox) to avoid checking for TextDataFormat:

```
private void mnuCopy_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    txtRichtext.Copy();
}

private void mnuPaste_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    txtRichtext.Paste();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a better solution (based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7661357/2263683)):

```
var dto = new DataObject();
dto.SetText(richTextBox.SelectedRtf, TextDataFormat.Rtf);
//Since notepad sux and doesn't understand \n, 
//we need to fix it replacing by Environment.NewLine (\r\n)
string unformattedText = richTextBox.SelectedText.Replace("\n", Environment.NewLine);
dto.SetText(unformattedText, TextDataFormat.UnicodeText);
Clipboard.Clear();
Clipboard.SetDataObject(dto);
```