# How to programmatically replace some content of WPF RichTextBox without loosing the formatting?

Tags: c#, wpf, richtextbox, rtf

**Question**: How can we programmatically replace some text in a `WPF RichTextBox` without loosing its formatting? In the following code I am clearly not doing something right. My online search gives some relevant suggestions but they seem to be using Winform where RichTextBox has rtf property - such as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4905479/1232087) one.

Following code correctly replaces text `abcd` with `rstu` inside a [WPF RichTexBox](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/controls/richtextbox-overview?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8) but it looses the formatting of the RichTextBox as shown in the two images below:

```
//rtbTest is the name of the RichTextBox
TextRange textRange = new TextRange(rtbTest.Document.ContentStart, rtbTest.Document.ContentEnd);
string oldText = textRange.Text;
string newText = oldText.Replace("abcd", "rstu");
textRange.Text = newText;
```

**Screenshot of RichTextBox BEFORE replacing abcd with rstu**:

[image]

**Screenshot of RichTextBox AFTER replacing abcd with rstu**:

As we can see the formatting is lost. The list shown below is not really a formatted numbered list, it probably is just unformatted text (like `1.    Item 1` etc.)

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is losing the formatting because you are storing the RTF into a string and the string doesn't keep RTF formatting.

You can preserve it as following,

```
TextRange textRange = new TextRange(rtbTest.Document.ContentStart, rtbTest.Document.ContentEnd);
string rtf;
using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
{
    textRange.Save(memoryStream, DataFormats.Rtf);
    rtf = ASCIIEncoding.Default.GetString(memoryStream.ToArray());
}

rtf = rtf.Replace("abcd", "rstu");


MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(ASCIIEncoding.Default.GetBytes(rtf));
rtbTest.SelectAll();
rtbTest.Selection.Load(stream, DataFormats.Rtf);
```

[image]

Comment: Manipulating with **RTF document** this way will not work in some cases and  might even damage the document content. For example, include `\r\n` characters to a document and try to replace it by  `rtf = rtf.Replace(@"\r\n", "rstu");`.

Comment: @AbdullahLeghari Your suggestion does correctly keep the formatting, but for some reasons, it eliminates default distance between lines. For example, as you can see in image 2 of my post, the distance between lines are removed. Same thing is happening in your suggested code except that your code correctly displays the list now. The declaration of my RichTextBox is as follows. So, I'm not sure why it's happening: `<RichTextBox x:Name="rtbTest" AcceptsTab="True" FontFamily="Calibri"/>`

Comment: @nam you can set the line height as desired, put this as last line of code I shared, `rtbTest.SetValue(Paragraph.LineHeightProperty, 10.0);`

Comment: @AbdullahLeghari And I noticed that the issue described above has nothing to do with your code replacing the text (for example `abcd` with `rstu`). Because even if comment out the line `rtf = rtf.Replace("abcd", "rstu");` from your code, the code runs fine but eliminates the default distance between the lines.

Comment: @AbdullahLeghari The `10.0` in `rtbTest.SetValue(Paragraph.LineHeightProperty, 10.0);` did not make any difference, but `25.0` did. This may be a different issue. So, I'll post a different post for it - as there may be other alternatives to resolve it. You did, however. answer my original issue (thank you).

Comment: @nam the 10.0 was just an example. LineHeightProperty defaults to pixels. You didn't notice a difference because 10 pixels is too low to be noticed probably.

Comment: Documented here, 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.documents.block.lineheight?view=net-5.0

Comment: And, glad to be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

When modifying the `RichTextBox` content it's very important to analyzing the `TextPointer` context. How it can be implemented see in the example below:

*MainWindow.xaml*

```
<Window ...
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="500">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>            
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RichTextBox x:Name="rtb" AllowDrop="True" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" Padding="2">
            <FlowDocument>
                <Paragraph>
                    <Run Text="Paste a content to the document..."/>                                      
                </Paragraph>
            </FlowDocument>
        </RichTextBox>
        <Button Grid.Row="1" Click="FindAndReplace">Find &amp; Replace </Button>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Part of the *MainWindow.xaml.cs*

```cs
using System;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Documents;

private void FindAndReplace(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var textToFind = "ABC";
    var textReplaceBy = "<A-B-C>";

    TextPointer start = rtb.Document.ContentStart;
    while (true)
    {
        var searchRange = new TextRange(start, rtb.Document.ContentEnd);
        TextRange foundRange = searchRange.FindText(textToFind);
        if (foundRange == null)
            break;

        foundRange.Text = textReplaceBy;             
        start = foundRange.End; // Continue the searching 
    }
    rtb.Focus();
}
```

*TextRangeExt.cs*

```cs
using System;
using System.Windows.Documents;

namespace WpfApp7
{
    public static class TextRangeExt
    {
        public static TextRange FindText(this TextRange searchRange, string searchText)
        {
            TextRange result = null;
            int offset = searchRange.Text.IndexOf(searchText, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
            if (offset >= 0)
            {
                var start = searchRange.Start.GetTextPositionAtOffset(offset);
                result = new TextRange(start, start.GetTextPositionAtOffset(searchText.Length));
            }
            return result;
        }

        private static TextPointer GetTextPositionAtOffset(this TextPointer position, int offset)
        {
            for (TextPointer current = position; current != null; current = position.GetNextContextPosition(LogicalDirection.Forward))
            {
                position = current;
                var adjacent = position.GetAdjacentElement(LogicalDirection.Forward);
                var context = position.GetPointerContext(LogicalDirection.Forward);
                switch (context)
                {
                    case TextPointerContext.Text:
                        int count = position.GetTextRunLength(LogicalDirection.Forward);
                        if (offset <= count)
                        {
                            return position.GetPositionAtOffset(offset);
                        }
                        offset -= count;
                        break;
                    case TextPointerContext.ElementStart:
                        if (adjacent is InlineUIContainer)
                        {
                            offset--;
                        }
                        else if (adjacent is ListItem lsItem)
                        {
                            var trange = new TextRange(lsItem.ElementStart, lsItem.ElementEnd);
                            var index = trange.Text.IndexOf('\t');
                            if (index >= 0)
                            {
                                offset -= index + 1;
                            }                            
                        }
                        break;
                    case TextPointerContext.ElementEnd:
                        if (adjacent is Paragraph)
                            offset -= 2;                        
                        break;
                }
            }
            return position;
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for sharing your knowledge as it may help me (and others) while working on some other aspects (positing of paragraphs/lines etc.) of my `WPF RichTextBox`, as well.

Comment: @nam: Any further question on your post is welcome! :)