# Why LineHeight gets changed in WPF RichTexBox when reloading its content from a stream

Tags: c#, wpf, richtextbox, rtf

**Question**: Why the following code changes the default [LineHeight](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.documents.block.lineheight?view=net-5.0) in WPF RichTexBox to 0? What would be a proper way to fix the issue?

Xaml for `RichTextBox`:

```
<RichTextBox x:Name="rtbTest" AcceptsTab="True" FontFamily="Calibri"/>
```

**Code to reload content of RichTexBox from stream**:

```
TextRange textRange = new TextRange(rtbTest.Document.ContentStart, rtbTest.Document.ContentEnd);
string rtf;
using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
{
    textRange.Save(memoryStream, DataFormats.Rtf);
    rtf = ASCIIEncoding.Default.GetString(memoryStream.ToArray());
}

//rtf = rtf.Replace("abcd", "rstu");

using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(ASCIIEncoding.Default.GetBytes(rtf)))
{
    rtbTest.SelectAll();
    rtbTest.Selection.Load(stream, DataFormats.Rtf);
}
```

**Screenshot of RichTexBox before running the above code**:

[image]

**Screenshot of RichTexBox AFTER running the above code**:

You notice that the default [LinHeight](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.documents.block.lineheight?view=net-5.0) got changed to 0.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `DataFormats.Rtf` format don't preserve line spacing. Use `DataFormats.Xaml` instead (doesn’t support images). Or even the `DataFormats.XamlPackage`: it will save and restore images too.

Comment: Your code posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66925347/1232087) also seems to be a proper way of modifying contents of a `RichTexBox`. I just tested it and your code modified the content without effecting any formatting (did not remove the LineHeight etc.). Thank you for sharing your knowledge.